# Vertical scrollbar setValue always sets it to 90

Tags: java, scrollbar, jscrollpane, setvalue

I'm saving the state of two scrollbars and loading it with these two methods:

```
private void saveScrollPosition() {
    scrollY = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
    scrollX = scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue();
    System.out.println("Saved: " + scrollX + "," + scrollY);
}

private void loadScrollPosition() {
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollY);
    scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().setValue(scrollX);
    System.out.println("Should load: " + scrollX + "," + scrollY);
    System.out.println("Loaded: " + scrollPane.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue() + "," + scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue());
}
```

The horizontal scrollbar is doing what it is supposed to do but the vertical is always set to 90.

> **Console:**
>   Saved: 185,882
>   Should load: 185,882
>   Loaded: 185,90

Found a tip in a forum to create a new Runnable method and start it with

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(doScroll);
```

but it didn't work out.

I wonder what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Just throwing it for chance, how are your `minimum` and `maximum - visibleAmount` setted?

Comment: Currently don't have the project with me. I'll check it on monday morning.

Comment: Max and min is set to the correct amount. Around 2000 for my window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update my contentPane first. Then the vertical scrollbar got updated to the correct values. Idk why it worked with the horizontal scrollbar...

Before:

```
loadScrollPosition();  
contentPane.updateUI();
```

After

```
contentPane.updateUI();
loadScrollPosition();
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. If somebody still has this problem, here is my situation:

My `JScrollPane` gets constructed new every time and at this moment the maximum of the `VerticalScrollBar` was set to 100, so it couldn't accept a higher value.

I fixed it by saving the maximum before constructing the new `JScrollPane` and then set it to the new Object.

```
if (scrollPane != null) {
    scrollPos = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
    maxScrollPos = scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().getMaximum();
}
scrollPane = new JScrollPane(panel);
if (scrollPos != null && maxScrollPos != null) {
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setMaximum(maxScrollPos);
    scrollPane.getVerticalScrollBar().setValue(scrollPos);
}
```